# Show Apache scoreboard when server does not respond

Tags: apache-2.4

I have an Apache server that stops responding every now and then. I would like to see its scoreboard to understand the reason, but the only way to access it I know is through `mod_status`, which is not usable because the server does not respond.

Is there another way to see the scoreboard?

It is Apache 2.4.38 from Debian buster.

Comment: Apache mods are not a necessary or advisable way of troubleshooting, please provide errors message and logs etc.

Comment: I don't want to use the mod, I want to see the scoreboard, which exists even without the mod. Is there a way do see it?

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, and wanted to see the (mod)status. I would "hide" it from the rest of the world, and only permit access from "trusted" IPs. If the apache server is local. `127.0.0.1` would be enough. Otherwise you'll need to whitelist the IP you're coming from. The following accomplishes it:

```
<Location /SOMEPLACE>
    require ip 127.0.0.1 yo.ur.e.ip
</Location>
```

Replacing `/SOMEPLACE` with where you enable mod_status
This way, only **you** will have access to the Apache (mod)status page(s).

Comment: The status request is served by apache too. If the server connections are exausted, he won't be able to request the status. Maybe a solution is to keep a browser (or some monitor software) connected and refreshing before the problem arises.

Comment: Right, my question is another. I want to access `mod_status` information without using `mod_status`, because at the point where I need it, my server is not able to reply any request any more.

Comment: @JucaPirama Right. But you can **log** that information **separately**. Thereby keeping a record of _what_ went wrong. Additional information from the Apache24 page: "A machine-readable version of the status file is available by accessing the page http://your.server.name/server-status?auto. This is useful when automatically run, see the Perl program log_server_status, which you will find in the /support directory of your Apache HTTP Server installation." In the end, it doesn't appear the OP is interested in this route. Even tho it provides clues needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @GiovanniMascellani You can't. Your best approach would be saving (using a monitoring tool, like zabbix or ganglia) the output of mod_status **before** the problem arises, then analysing the info behaviour the moments before the server goes unresponsive.